# spec has no expectations when using expect within subscribe

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to create a test to validate the value returned from an Observable within my service:

```
  private userIsRegisteringToggle = new Subject<void>();

  userIsRegistering$: Observable<boolean> = this.userIsRegisteringToggle.asObservable().pipe(
    scan(previous => !previous, false),
    startWith(false)
  );

 toggleUserIsRegistering() {
   this.userIsRegisteringToggle.next();
  }
```

This is the test:

```
 it('should contain true value when value is toggled', fakeAsync((done: DoneFn) => {
      service.toggleUserIsRegistering();
      flush();
      service.userIsRegistering$.pipe(skip(1))
      .subscribe(value => {
          expect(value).toEqual(true);
          done();
      });
 }));
```

The test keeps returning this:

> SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS should contain true value when value is toggled

The test itself passes however.

I've tried using `fakeAsync()` with `Flush()` to clear the task queue and I've tried using the `Done()` function to mark any async tasks as complete but nothing seems to be working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an issue of late subscribing with a subject. Try to subscribe first and then do the actions.

```
 it('should contain true value when value is toggled', fakeAsync((done: DoneFn) => {
      service.userIsRegistering$.pipe(skip(1))
      .subscribe(value => {
          expect(value).toEqual(true);
          done();
      });
      service.toggleUserIsRegistering();
      flush();
 }));
```

If that doesn't work, try removing the `skip(1)` to see if it gives you any other hints as to why it doesn't work.